# Delay touchstart event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, cordova

I'm building an iOS app using cordova and I'm using touchstart for click events. However, the positioning of some buttons are fixed and the buttons will have different href values dependent on the current page.

The issue I'm currently facing is when you click on a link on one page and the app loads the next page, it still reads the current touch and fires the next available link on the new page.

Example (to hopefully aid the explanation):

The white button is in the same position as the purple button, and they're on completely separate pages. The white button takes you to the page with the purple button and 8/10 one single touch will fire both buttons on the device.

[image: button one]

[image: button two]

How do I stop this from happening? Changing the position of the buttons is not an option.

Comment: can you show some code? Just to check the id/class of the buttons, the way you bind events on the buttons etc...

Comment: They share the same class for style purposes (cta-btn) but each button has it's own unique identifier and these are what's targeted in the javascript. eg: $('.proceed').on('touchstart', ...);

Comment: and when do you bind the events? for what i can see you bind the events through a class. You can think, if it's not already like this, to bind these events inside the 'pageshow' event's callback of each page: `$('#page1').on('touchstart', '.proceed', function() {...});` and the different behavior for `$('#page2').on('touchstart', '.proceed', function() {...});`. page1 and page2 are 2 ids that you give to the div with the "page" role.

Comment: I've tried this way and it still does the same thing. It's as if the actual touch event is way too sensitive or something? This only happens when I test it on my actual iPhone